thoughts about wrting a package like titlesec and titletoc
Today, with LaTeX3 and some x<package>s being relatively mature, such as xtemplate and xparse, I think it is necessary to write a package about title-sec and toc making based on them. The reality seems to be the case, for that i saw the xcontents package based on xtemplate in the LaTeX3 project repository.
sec and toc are two very important basic parts in LaTeX, but I think the existing commands or packages are not so unified and complete. Till now, packages related to this problem are basically only titlesec, titletoc, and tocloft (maybe secsty). But I think the interfaces they provide are not unified (they are all different packages, so they are naturally not unified), or the interfaces are not so user-friendly. Some beginners think that titlesec is kind of hard or error-prone to use, see these comments from CTAN:

Figuring out the parameters takes some time, but the flexibility is worth it. When writing a thesis with strict standards for everything such packages are priceless.


Title format changes work as expected. The \titleformat command has over 6 parameters, which is a bit error-prone, but the terse format setting does the job.

Moreover, the original formats related to these sec commands in LaTeX are also difficult to customize. In most cases, you need to make a series of patches or copy the original declaration and redefine it into the format you want.
In addition, there are some large bundles, such as koma-script and memoir, which also provide unified and complete interfaces related to sec and toc customization. However, the premise of using them is that you need to use the document class they provide you. In fact, many times, you don’t want to use a document class you are not familiar with just for these sec and toc commands.
Thus, i want to write a macro package to replace the original titlesec and titletoc or tocloft, in which i will provide my own commands, such as \chapter, \section, ..., \tableofcontents, titlecontents,... (and i will call these commands as sec commands in the following; and use toc commands to refer these related to TOC typesetting). So what issues should I consider when defining such commands? Or what do I need to accomplish in these commands ?
1. Consideration
The following are what I want to accomplish in these commands, or the aspects I consider:

The hook interface inside the command, although LaTeX already has some generic hooks. But I think more hook interfaces are needed for these kind of commands.
The corresponding marker command processing which is used to process headers. With the improvement of the new marker mechanism, can we consider re-implementing commands such as \sectionmark and \chaptermark
The generation of the TOC and its format control may require a module similar to titletoc at the same time (Although there are already macro packages like xcontents and tocloft). Moreover, if you want to customize the TOC format, you may need to rewrite the \contentsline command, or simply stop using this command ?
IMHO, interface of the sec and toc commands plus their format customization should be integrated, and should not be separated. The titlesec package does take this into consideration, but it is still not thorough enough. Consider a situation that we want to typeset the table of contents multiple times in an article, for example, a partial table of contents for a chapter, although this function, namely \titlecontents, is already provided in titletoc.
Counters and labels update, such as \stepcounter and \refstepcounter, are used to handle commands related to counters and labels. You also need hyperlinks provided by hyperref to work properly. Besides, you need to make commands such as \nameref and \autoref work properly. cleveref should be taken into consideration as well .
For sec commands that need to occupy a full page, such as \part commands, the page style of the current page needs to be specified inside, although the titleps package also provides this.
The spacing before and after these sec commands, including the corresponding page-breaking issues, etc., if your title is very long, or you need to consider the title crossing pages. Perhaps it is necessary to consider the page-breaking algorithm of LaTeX, the related Output Routine(the inserted objects therein) ? For example, titlesec cannot handle the penalty problem in the custom format well.
The format of the sec command itself, as the shapes(hang, block, wrap, etc) provided in the titlesec macro package. And it should also provide an interface similar to the explicit option in titlesec. Sometimes, we may need to use packages such as tikz, tcolorbox to complete the format customization of our sec commands.
Compatibility with other packages (I personally think this is the most difficult part): Some packages may rely on the original commands of LaTeX, such as \@sect, \@startsection, etc. Or some packages will make certain changes to the original sec commands or make certain patches, such as hyperref.
Provide a command similar to \titleclass in titlesec package to create new sec commands, which is similar to this command provided in titlesec. However, this is unnecessary for a single document class. For example, you don’t need to create a \chapter command in article, but if you want to develop a basic document class, then you need to provide such an interface and leave the specific implementation of these sec commands to the class author.

Are there any other issues or tasks that need to be considered?
These itmes(issues or plans) i considered above are based on my current understanding of LaTeX before writing this package. However, till now, it seems that things have become very complicated :-(. This may be the reason why such packages are so rare. This project is really huge and difficult.
2. Some thoughts
Moreover, I think it is unrealistic to redeclare these sec and toc commands. Many basic document classes are based on commands like \@sect, \@startsection and so forth. If you redeclare them all, it seems a bit too extreme.

Is this the reason why these interfaces are retained today?

In order to maintain the compatibility of most basic macro packages and document classes? Then does it mean that I can only insert these custom format based on the original commands
provided in LaTeX2e, like titlesec, instead of providing a brand new implementation to make such sec and toc commands ?

The first thought I had: https://xkcd.com/927/.  I think it would be better to see if you could contribute directly to the existing packages and see if you can make a more user friendly interface.

@Teepeemm Indeed, it is more realistic to improve an exsiting packages.

Also don't forget that Section names can appear in the headers and/or footers as well as the Table of Contents. Like @Teepeemm, I would suggest looking at the existing packages (titlesec, titletoc, and titleps) to see if they can be improved or (easily) combined, rather than starting from scratch. Other packages which do similar things are sectsty, tocloft, and fancyhdr, so those might be some to look at as well.

how much experience do you have writing packages for LaTeX? because this is is not a good first project, imho. you say you want to write a package to 'replace ...'. that's not how it works. you can write a competitor, but users will decide whether and how to use it.

also: tagging. there are rather more packages for the features you mentioned than you list, too ;).

the reason legacy interfaces are retained is to prevent breaking documents - not packages. latex is committed to backwards compatibility. that means some things in the format can't be changed, even if they are obvious bugs. one person's bug is another person's feature.

@cfr If i write it, then this will be my first project.  As for 'wrting experience', I have worked on a bundle for nearly one year, but today comes the hardest part, namely, the sec and toc in this question. That why i ask this question. For the reasons mentioned above,  I may write a competitor.

compability with the tagging code in latex-lab is very important.
